# Graphing 2d plane in 3d space using equation and/or vectors

Tags: javascript, math, 3d, three.js

I'm trying to make a linear regression plane visualization tool for a math project. Currently I have the math parts completed, but I am not sure how to graph the plane. I have a equation in the form of z=C+xD+yE, where C, D, and E are known constants. How do I graph the plane using these information? Thanks.

github page: https://saxocellphone.github.io/LAProject/

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: No im working on this just for practice. I just finished linear algebra in school and we'really doing independent study, so I chose to study how linear algebra can be used in programming.

Comment: Provide a link to your live testbed and ask a specific question if you are not able to place the plane mesh in the scene correctly.

Comment: I updated the post. The specific question is how do I efficiently represent a plane using three.js given a 3d function. I tired many methods but none of them seemed to work.

Comment: Excellent. Now all you need to do is either (1) add a mesh to the scene using `PlaneGeometry` and having the correct `position` and `rotation` (or `quaternion`), or (2) add a mesh to the scene in the form of a [single triangle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046897/how-to-make-a-custom-triangle-in-three-js),  and whose vertices lie on the coordinate axes in the right places.

Comment: Ok thanks. I think I will try the first way. I looked up quaternions and they look sort of confusing, but I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @user1932868 check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37506180/three-js-construct-plane-through-points-on-axes, I'd suggest you implement it with the concepts I described before checking the implementation

Answer (score 0):

```
 z=C+xD+yE
```

This equation gives full information about the plane. What else you need to graph (plot, draw?) it? Probably it depends on your graphic software possibilities.
Canonical form of given equation:

```
 xD + yE - z + C = 0
```

Normal to the plane is `(D, E, -1)`. Distance to the coordinate origin `Abs(C)/Sqrt(D^2+E^2+1)`.

Plane intersects coordinate axes at values `(-C/D), (-C/E), (C)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I think I understand what you are doing. However, I still cannot graph it using Three.js. The only way to make a plane using three.js is to specify the width and the height (you can rotate it and change the position). Is there anyway to work around that?

Comment: Planes have no width and height

Comment: I mean I just need a representation of a plane, so basically I just need to make a square. The documentation is http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Geometries/PlaneGeometry

Answer (score 0):

I see your problem is not with math, but with three,
as WestLangley pointed out in his comment you can play with rotations etc. or create a simple triangle which is the easiest way

since you have your equation for the plane create 3 points to form a triangle

```
// z=C+xD+yE
// i assume here that the plane is not aligned with any axis 
// and does not pass through the origin, otherwise choose the points in another way
var point1 = new THREE.Vector3(-C/D,0,0);//x axis intersection
var point2 = new THREE.Vector3(0,-C/E,0);//y axis intersection
var point3 = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,C);//z axis intersection
```

now form a new geometry as in [How to make a custom triangle in three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046897/how-to-make-a-custom-triangle-in-three-js)

```
var geom = new THREE.Geometry(); 
geom.vertices.push(point1);// adding vertices to geometry
geom.vertices.push(point2);
geom.vertices.push(point3);
// telling geometry that vertices 0,1,2 form a face = triangle
geom.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 2 ) );
```

create a simple material and add it to a scene

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xff0000, // RGB hex color for material
    side: THREE.DoubleSide // do not hide object when viewing from back
});
scene.add(new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material));
```

that should get you going, you can add another triangles, or make it larger with choosing points that are further apart

Comment: Oh lol thanks for the help! However, I been looking at quaternions and they seem extremely useful. I really want learn rotating objects using quaternions because I read that they are useful for game and graphic designers. I'm only beginning to understand it, so it will probably be a while before I use it.