# Three.js: Construct plane through points on axes

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to create a plane that passes through (say) 2 on the x-axis, 3 on the y-axis and 12 on the z-axis (in other words, the plane 6x + 4y + z = 12).

I've so far tried creating a horizontal plane and rotating it around the 3 axes using the dot product, which gave me close to the desired plane, but it would never be exactly right.

I suspect I need to use Matrix4, but couldn't find a suitable example.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090305/graphing-2d-plane-in-3d-space-using-equation-and-or-vectors/

Comment: `6 x 2 + 4  x 3 + 12 = 36`

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to build it, from your example you have three vectors which are multiples of the canonical basis `i,j,k` e.g.

```
x = x_0 * [1 0 0]
y = y_0 * [0 1 0]
z = z_0 * [0 0 1]
```

A plane is defined with two things:

- a normal (a vector perpendicular to the plane)
- a distance from the origin to the plane

The normal can be built from the cross product of any two non-parallel vectors that lie on the plane, e.g. `y - x` and `z - x` therefore

```
normal = normalize(cross(y - x, z - x))
```

Now when the plane is rendered it will have an initial normal `N`, we can create a quaternion rotates the vector `N` to `normal`, I'll use the axis angle form where

```
q_{axis} = cross(N, normal)
q_{angle} = acos(dot(N, normal))
```

Next the distance to the plane can be found with the dot product of the normal and any point on the plane e.g.

```
distance = dot(normal, x)
```

Note that this is a signed value which is awesome since all you have to do to move the plane is move it `distance` units in the normal direction

### Implementation

```
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 10),
  new new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial()
)
// ...
function rotatePlane(x, y, z) {
  var xy = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(y, x)
  var xz = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(z, x)
  var normal = new THREE.Vector3().crossVectors(xy, xz).normalize()

  // initial normal vector of the plane
  var Z = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1)
  var axis = new THREE.Vector3().crossVectors(Z, normal).normalize()
  var angle = Math.acos(Z.dot(normal))
  var q = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromAxisAngle(axis, angle)
  plane.rotation.setFromQuaternion(q)

  var distanceToPlane = x.dot(normal)
  plane.position.copy(normal.clone().multiplyScalar(distanceToPlane))
}
```

### [Demo](http://codepen.io/maurizzzio/pen/GjAPYj?editors=0010)

Edit 1: as @WestLangley commented you can use `plane.quaternion.setFromUnitVectors( Z, normal )` which under the hood simplifies the quaternion described above by avoiding the use of trig functions among other things, you can read more about the simplification in this awesome [article](http://lolengine.net/blog/2013/09/18/beautiful-maths-quaternion-from-vectors)

Edit 2: @WestLangley added a comment about the direction of the normal which is completely valid, in the implementation instead of checking for this I decided to render both faces of the triangles that make the plane, if you also want to make the plane to never look at the origin first you realize from the above equations that if `distance` is negative that means that the plane moved away from the origin while looking at it, if this happens you need to flip the direction of the `normal` which also makes `distance` to always be positive

```
if (distance < 0) {
  distance *= -1
  normal.multiplyScalar(-1)
}
```

Comment: (1) Simpler solution: `plane.quaternion.setFromUnitVectors( Z, normal );` (2) Your normal appears to have the wrong sign if `x` is negative, for example.

Comment: Actually, if you want to keep the top edge of the plane horizontal, `plane.lookAt( normal );` would be best.

Comment: @WestLangley Thanks for the feedback :), I've updated the demo implementing your suggestions

Comment: @Mauricio: Thanks for your great answer. Won't the rotatePlane() function be expensive within the render function? It works fine outside, so doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: @WestLangley: I do actually want to keep the top edge of the plane horizontal, but not sure how to modify Mauricio's answer to use lookAt.

Comment: @MBourne Replace `plane.rotation.setFromQuaternion( q )` with `plane.lookAt( normal );`.

Comment: @MBourne This was a demo, try to adjust it to your needs

Comment: @WestLangley: Thank you, however I'm using `camera.up = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 1 )` and I found `plane.lookAt( normal );` did not give horizontal top. (In Mauricio's second demo, `plane.lookAt( normal );` worked perfectly, but fails when adding camera.up.

Comment: (1) `camera.up.set( 0, 0, 1 );`  (2) `plane.up.set( 0, 0, 1 );` (3) `plane.lookAt( normal )`.